# Multiple hashtag routes in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, hash, routes

I've got a project that requires a lot of user-input. It's basically a puzzle with six pieces, and the pieces are triggered by hashtag routes. Easy enough, right? I guess.

I have a great setup right now, where when a hash is reached("www.website.com/index.html/#test"), the first piece will appear. Now, this is great and all, but the thing is, the pieces can be triggered in any order, at any time. So if I had the following routes - "1", "2", "3", etc, it needs to be able to be something like: ("www.website.com/index.html/#3/#1/#2") or something similar. I can worry about making it look good at a later time, after I've figured out how to make it functional in the first place.

Here's the route code that I currently have -

```
<script>
    $(function(){

    var hideOne = function () {
        //alert("hideOne");
        var elem = document.getElementById("one");
        elem.className = "hide";
    };

    var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "test":"test",// #test
      },    
      test: hideOne
    });

    var router = new Workspace();
    Backbone.history.start(); 

});
</script>
```

So my question is; how do I make it so that I can have multiple hashtag routes in backbone.js?

Thanks in advance.

-Mitchyl

Comment: This is not how you want to build multiple routes. maybe like #1/2/3. The hashtag delimits the end of the path and query string and the beginning of the fragment.

Comment: @w1zeman1p Oh, alright. Do you know how I would go about building multiple routes then? Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: yeah so in your routes object you can add another property with another function to call. maybe something like routes: { "test/1", hideAnotherOne } where hideAnotherOne is a different function. I guess if you had a bit more context i could be more specific :)

Comment: @w1zeman1p Sorry for the late reply, I hope you're still browsing this question!  Basically, the hashes trigger different functions which apply classes to certain images. Each has will trigger the function on a different image. So, if I want image 1 and 3 to display, they'll need to have the hash for both 1 and 3. I hope that's a bit more specific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. Where you browse to stuff.com/path#hide/one/three
here the routes with the (/:x) around them are dynamic matchers. so the () means it's optional and the :x means it will pass the string value from that part of the url fragment as an argument to the function called when the route is matched. So if your number of images is bounded to something pretty small this should be fine, I think.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var hideMany = function () {
      var toHide = [].slice.call(arguments);
      toHide.forEach(function (id) {
        if(id === null) { return }
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        if(elem) {
          elem.className = "hide";
        }
      });
    };

    var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "hide(/:a)(/:b)(/:c)" : "test"
      },
      test: hideMany
    });

    var router = new Workspace();
    Backbone.history.start();

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Looks really neat, I think I'll give it a try. I'm a bit confused though. Would this be able to trigger _specific_ elements to hide? Like could I bind (/:a) to "image1", (/:b) to "image2", etc?

Comment: yeah so if you want it to hide image1 you would enter the #hide/image1/image3 where image1 and image3 are the ids of the elements in the page.

Comment: I'm really confused(sorry, I'm not grasping this concept that well). Do I need to change the (/:a)'s and (:/b)'s to the IDs of my elements? Or should it already work with the current setup. Thanks for your helpful comments though, I think I'm starting to get it.

EDIT: Nevermind! I've figured it out